# Is kafka streaming driver waiting for executors to finish?

Tags: spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming application that monitors some messages from kafka. For a specific message I may need to go to a long loop to continue pinging some ip until its reconnected.
What I can see that when some executor goes to this loop, it stops processing the stream.
Is it correct ? 
How can I make this loop without interrupting continuing processing the stream ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the executors will not progress if they are blocked on a long-running task.

I would advise against running such long process on an executor. Assuming that those reconnect cases are sparse in time, I would use an asynchronous process in the driver. (Futures or barebone threads from a pool).